# PyCharm doesn't show possible args to sklearn make_classification() function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycharm, keyword-argument

It is a bit strange that in PyCharm IDE,  [`sklearn.datasets.make_classification()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html) function does not show me  possible  inner arguments, only *args and **kwargs are showing.

i have installed latest version of Pycharm,i dont know if it is reason, maybe there is some  parameter- which need to be  changed? please advice me what to do?

it is how pycharm is showing(it is 2021 version)
[image]

Comment: What's your version? I have PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.5

Comment: Try instead using the fully qualified name `sklearn.datasets.make_classification()`, does this still happen? I suspect PyCharm IDE does not instantly resolve the imports so it doesn't know where `make_classification()` comes from, hence its arg signature.

Comment: Look for a ⚠️yellow warning exclamation sign in the top right, click on it, I get a warning *"Cannot find reference 'make_classification' in '__init__.py'"*. Somehow PyCharm is not resolving the import correctly. Dig into this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to investigate:

- Try instead using the fully qualified name `sklearn.datasets.make_classification()`, does this still happen? I suspect PyCharm IDE does not instantly resolve the imports so it doesn't know where `make_classification()` comes from, hence its arg signature.
- Look for a ⚠️yellow warning exclamation sign in the top right, click on it, I get a warning *"Cannot find reference 'make_classification' in '**init**.py'"*. Somehow PyCharm is not resolving the import correctly.

  - Dig into this: click on that warning, PyCharm will open the warning in the 'Problems' window, then right-click on that, and look at PyCharm's suggested list of 'Show Quick Fixes' (not that any of its three suggestions would solve this, but it gives insight into why PyCharm is failing to resolve the import. See if you can fix the import so the warning goes away)
- does this happen on other functions with positional and keyword args?
- did you close and reopen PyCharm and recheck?
- When I browse to the sklearn source, I see that function is covered by a
  `@_deprecate_positional_args` decorator. That might be affecting PyCharm behavior. But you'd still expect PyCharm to show keyword args.

  - does PyCharm only not show args on functions with a `@_deprecate_positional_args` decorator?
  - try commenting out `@_deprecate_positional_args` decorator in your source, saving and reloading, does it still do this?
- can you post a screenshot of what it does highlight?

My current version is PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.5

Comment: i have updated , it showing only  *args and **kwargs inside function

Comment: thank you my friend, actually i know this function even with  closes eyes(but it is surprise, maybe new version of pycharm has some bugs)

Comment: Uhuh. Maybe people with other versions can state their version and comment if they experience this or not. Have you checked [their issues list](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY)? by version. If not, please do raise an issue on JetBrains. Keep screenshots.

Comment: ...obviously before you raise a new issue, search the existing issues first to see if it isn't a known issue (and paste number and link here if it is)

Comment: @datodatuashvili: to document and fix this esp. if it's an issue introduced in recent version of PyCharm. Help open-source development back...